# Using non Typescript library in Typescript with eslint

Tags: typescript

I am pretty new to Typescript and trying to figure out how to use an external non-typescript library with typescript. I have a library initialization code like below:

```html
initPlugin(function (config: any) {
    return {
        styles: 'dark',
        controlOptions: config.controlOptions
    }
})
```

The code is working fine with type 'any' on the config parameter. However, using 'any' will throw a warning from eslint to specify a different type. Something like this:

warning  Unexpected any. Specify a different type  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any

The config parameter has so many properties that I might use in the future.

What methods should I use to remove the warning and also the efficient way to writing types from the config parameter? (without changing the config of eslint)

Comment: There's a type `object` which is slightly more specific than `any`, but I'm pretty sure ESLint will flag that too. If you don't want to fully define the type for `config`, and don't want to change your ESLint config either, the only thing I can think to do is disable the `any` check just where you need to, with: `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any`

Comment: Thank you for helping, it really helped me make my decision. In the end, I prefer to change the eslint configuration, I think it's better for time efficiency.